# Git LFS Error: OID Confused

Tags: git, github

We've just started using Github's new Large File Storage (LFS) system. And I cannot push in one of my branches because of the following error:

```
Expected db/australia-latest.osm.pbf to have an OID of 443c6d85a3f849911146a5c7836d293e145983312c3bc12564968846d95c3245, got 1c83c9cd15655a17a27eaa25a9cab10a919006535f0e10b88f50f1b144976765
```

At some stage the file was accidentally deleted and re-added by one of the developers so this is probably why the oids are confused, but at this point in time, I cannot push (even with the -f method).

Has anyone else seen this error and/or know how it can be resolved?

Thanks in advance,

Jake